# A normalized javascript implementation of the Date type?

Tags: javascript, date

`new Date("2")` is:

- "Thu Feb 01 2001 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)" on Chrome
- "Invalid Date" on Firefox and IE 9
- "Thu, 01 Feb 2001 05:00:00 GMT" on node.js

Since node.js uses the google V8 javascript engine and Chrome is also from google, I suppose this is a googlish tweak.

This is bad. Is there an easy way to normalize the behavior of the `Date` type across the different platforms?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Of course, "2" is not good for a date. But if one uses the "date" method of the jQuery validator plugin, then "2" is a perfectly valid input, because this particular validation method defers its logic to the `Date` javascript type to make the actual validation. Which makes perfect sense, if the `Date` type implementation is sensible. Which is apparently not the case in Chrome (and node.js).

Comment: Why is this bad? Just don't feed date with an unsupported string with side effects.[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date): dateString: String value representing a date. The string should be in a format recognized by the parse method (IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps).

Comment: What would you like instead? `"2"` is pretty ambiguous for a date, so I'm not sure why you would use that for a date.

Comment: I don't think "2" is a valid timestamp, hence the difference of implementation. Using a valid timestamp will solve this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The ECMAScript specification states that the single parameter `Date` constructor, where that parameter is a string, will defer to `Date.parse` which is "implementation dependent". Source: [ECMAScript specification](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.4.2).

Avoid using this constructor therefore if you want the same behaviour across implementations.

If you have, for your application, a recognised meaning of the string `"2"` as a date, then you should implement your own logic to interpret it. There is no "standard" meaning for this. If you had something more recognisable to the world at large as your string, you'd find the different implementations behaved more similarly. But in your case you'd be advised to parse the string yourself and explicitly provide the meaning of the `2` to a more explicit constructor for `Date`.

Comment: This is cruel, because what you are suggesting is to avoid using both `new Date(string)` and `Date.parse(string)`.

Comment: You tell what not to do, which is good, but not as good as telling what yes to do. Do you mean that you always parse date strings manually to extract the date components and then invoke the `Date` constructor with them?

Comment: I've edited the answer. No, I don't always parse date strings manually. But if they are ambiguous or non-standard then I do.

Comment: As I mention in my question, "2" is not a valid date for me too. BUT, I am using jQuery validation plugin to validate user input and "2" validates! Because the "date" validation method delegates to the `Date` constructor.